# Non-blocking service to receive messages on port via UDP

Tags: linux, node.js

I want to build a service on my Linux VPS which listens to a certain UDP port and does something with the (text)message which is captured. This processing consists of appending the message to a locally stored txt-file and send it as http, with a post variable to another server.

---

I've looked into Nginx but  as far is can see this server can only be bound to receive http packets. Although it is asynchronous.

What is the best way to achieve this listening-service on linux? And which has the capabilities to do the above mentioned processing?

Is for instance node.js a possibilty? It looks great

Comment: We already have messaging protocols. [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/) is one that might fit your use case. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, you can use xinetd, and for the app you can use any scripting language, which will read the packet from the stdin and save it to the file.